# MVVM pattern in NativeScript - how to use one?

Tags: oop, nativescript

### The Problem

*I just cannot figure out the view model in NativeScript*

I am having a hard time understanding how view-models work in NativeScript. I understand the high level concept - that the MVVM pattern allows us to create observable objects - and our UI is updated when values change.

Here is a simple example:

**main-page.js**

```
var createViewModel = require("./main-view-model").createViewModel;

function onNavigatingTo(args) {

    var page = args.object;

    page.bindingContext = createViewModel();

}

exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;
```

**main-view-model.js**

```
var Observable = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable").Observable;

function getMessage(counter) {
    if (counter <= 0) {
        return "Hoorraaay! You unlocked the NativeScript clicker achievement!";
    } else {
        return counter + " taps left";
    }
}

function createViewModel() {
    var viewModel = new Observable();
    viewModel.counter = 42;
    viewModel.message = getMessage(viewModel.counter);

    viewModel.onTap = function() {
        this.counter--;
        this.set("message", getMessage(this.counter));
    }

    return viewModel;
}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

*I understand , some what, what is happening. But not everything.*

**Questions I Have ...**

1. How would you add a new function , for instance, an email validation function? Would it go into the View Model page, or just plain Javscript page?
2. Let's say I added a new textfield to the UI.  I have a tap function. Where does my function go?

So in this case, everything related to the UI should go in the createViewModel function? Is that correct?

I have also seen in sample apps, where the developer doesn't use view models at all - it appears he just creates it as an observable object.

Thank you for looking. I know I am close to understanding, but that **bindingContext** and the viewmodel has me a bit confused. [ I have read everything in NS docs ]

John

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **either of it should work**. You may put the validation or tap function in view model or in the code behind file, it's upto you to decide which works best for you.

If you put it in the view model, you will use event binding (`tap="{{ functionName }}"` Or if you put it in code behind file, you will just export the function name and simply refer the function name on XML (`tap="functionName"`).

By giving this flexibility you are allowed to separate your code, keep the files light weighted.

Comment: where is model here ? in android we use POJO classes to define models. can you explain why not using model here.

Comment: If you are using {N} core flavor, the Observable instance is your View Model that is assigned to bindingContext of any View, mostly the Page.

Comment: so Observable instance is itself works like model and view-model.